# Print all lines that don't have numbers, using sed

Tags: sed, numeric-data

I need to print all the lines containing non numeric characters using regex in sed.
The input is a csv, and some of it's lines has text and numbers. I'm interested in printing only those without numbers. This is what I tried:

```
sed -E -n '/^\D*$/p' direcciones.csv
```

Why it doesn't find anything?

Comment: Printing `all the lines containing non numeric characters` != printing `those [lines] without numbers`. The former will not print an empty line while the latter would print it. Which do you want?

Answer (score 10):

@steeldriver already explained why your attempt didn't work (should work with GNU `sed`, though).

But why not keep it simple? Printing all lines with only non-numeric characters is the same as dropping all lines with numeric characters:

```
sed '/[0-9]/d' direcciones.csv
```

Easier to write and easier to read, isn't it?

Comment: wrt `Printing all lines with only non-numeric characters is the same as dropping all lines with numeric characters` - not quite, consider lines that have no characters (except the terminating newline of course)

Comment: Maybe a matter of language precision. *"You are allowed to pass the border with only toll free products"* -- are you allowed to pass it without any products? Fortunally, regexp is more precise: `/^[^0-9]*$/` is linewise the same as `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 6):

Your implementation of sed likely doesn't support the PCRE extension `\D` (even with the `-E` extended regular expression switch) . You should be able to use `[^[:digit:]]` instead:

```
$ printf 'foo,bar,baz\nfoo,123,baz\n' | sed -n '/^[^[:digit:]]*$/p'
foo,bar,baz
```

Comment: AFAIK no sed supports `\d` or `\D` as they're PCRE escape sequences and no sed supports PCREs.

Comment: @EdMorton I suspected that was the case - but I was hesitant to assert it (especially since GNU sed does appear to support `\s` and `\S`)

Comment: Right, I was a little surprised when I noticed but GNU tools support \s, \S, \w, and \W in all REs (BREs, EREs, or PCREs) and GNU grep supports PCREs which include \d and \D but neither sed nor awk support PCREs and so don't support \d and \D.

Answer (score 5):

Are you restricted to `sed` only or can you use `grep`?

```
grep -v '[0-9]' direcciones.csv
```

Comment: That's not "all lines that don't have numbers" like the title says (and the `sed` attempt is trying to do), but all lines that are not entirely digits. You'd need `grep -v '[0-9]' direcciones.csv` instead

Comment: ...or `grep '^[^0-9]*$'`

Comment: @pLumo: The pattern you cite is suppose to mean "lines consisting only of non-digits (`\D`). The opposite is not "lines consisting of only digits", but "lines containing at least one digit"

Comment: I need to drink more coffeee... thanks for insisting :-p